# How can i check is valid MGRS number or not in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to check is the number is MGRS or not. but i am not able to find the solution. currently i am working on the following code.

```
    +(BOOL)isValidMGRS:(NSString *)str{

    NSString *mgrsRegex = @"(\\d{1,2})([C-X&&[^IO]])([A-Z&&[^IO]])([A-Z&&[^IO]])";
    NSPredicate *mgrsTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", mgrsRegex];
    return [mgrsTest evaluateWithObject:str];

}
```

but every time i am getting false
is there any other pattern to check MGRS number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and "MGRS number" is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system try:

```
+ (BOOL)isValidMGRS:(NSString *)str{
{       
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d{1,2})([C-X&&[^IO]])([A-Z&&[^IO]])([A-Z&&[^IO]])"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                             error:&error];
    NSRange range = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound && error == nil)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks i got the reasult